# Cant figure out return type of room db

Tags: android, android-room

My Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_entity_table")
internal data class MYEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val pcID: Int,
    val server_id: String,
    val name: String,
    val detail: String,
    val duration: Int,
    val start_date : Long,
    val end_date: Long,
    val created_by_user_id: String,
    val db_create_dttm: Long,
    val db_update_dttm: Long,
    val db_create_src: Long,
    val db_update_src: Long
)
```

My dao query where I to select the duration,start_date and end_date

```
@Query("select duration,start_date,end_date from my_entity_table where id =:pcID")
    suspend fun getDurationDetails(pcID:Int) : What should be the return type?
```

What should be the return type of the query ??

Comment: why not just select the corresponding entities and then use their properties ?

Comment: you can use same entity model class .

Comment: @androidLearner the project does not build if I do that there is an error which says that the remaining fields are not returned in the query although they are non null

Comment: I did not understand @a_local_nobody

Comment: As @Bogdan Android said, create new model class with fields that you want ,use that class as return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a specific data class as model for your query with the specific fields:

```
data class ExampleModel(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "duration") val duration: Int?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "start_date") val start_date: Long?
        @ColumnInfo(name = "end_date") val end_date: Long?
    )
```

And then use it as return:

```
@Query("select duration,start_date,end_date from my_entity_table where id =:pcID")
    suspend fun getDurationDetails(pcID:Int) : ExampleModel
```

I don't think that using the Entity model is posible cause your Entity parameters are not nullable and you query just a few of that parameters.